# JSPDF not working with click

Tags: jquery, html, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am trying to make a downloadable DIV content through JSPDF. here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/S3XRp/14/

and the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var doc = new jsPDF();

// We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer){
        return true;
    }
};

    $('#cmd').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#content').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="content">
 <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

<p>a pararaph</p>
     </div>
     <div id="editor"></div>
      <a href="#" id="cmd">generate PDF</a>
```

But its not working for me. I use newest Chrome..
thanks for any tips.

Comment: Working perfectly, http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/S3XRp/15/. You need to check console error. In my fiddle I have used `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.js` as external resource

Comment: You have probably forgot to load external resources like jspdf script source and jQuery 2.1+

Comment: @urbz, In OP fiddle, You will get console error `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined `

Comment: this is the updated fiddle used @Satpal comment
http://jsfiddle.net/sarahN/S3XRp/203/

Comment: @SarahN, What ^^^^^^ for?

Comment: @Satpal just because the last time I ran your link,it didnt work for me, so I added the resource files again , and thats because I added a comment. but now I checked it again, and they re the same!!!.